# Is it possible to change the behavior of the maximise buttons in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Is it possible to change the behaviour of the maximise window button in OS X Yosemite to match that of Mavericks and earlier versions (click to make window fill out screen)?

Really annoying since I almost never want apps to go fullscreen and keep forgetting to hold <kbd>alt</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/os-x-10-10-yosemite/) and the edits it offers:

> If you don’t like the new behavior of the green window button in Yosemite, you can now change it with BTT using the trigger “Leftclick Green Window Button” in the tab “Other” in BTT’s main preference window.

You can download it directly from [here](http://www.boastr.de/BetterTouchTool.zip)!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way of changing the default behaviour but there are two easy ways to do what you want:

1. Double-click the title bar of a window.
2. Hold the Alt key on the keyboard - you'll notice the icon on the green button changes from the new diagonal arrows to the old plus symbol.

Comment: Thanks, I´m going to keep this one open a while to see if any has come up with some crazy hacks.